# tictactoe with minimax in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, minimax

Its been 1 week since I am trying to make TicTacToe game in react. everything works except getting right evaluation from minimax algorithm. whenever i try to find bestMove() every position just gets same evaluation and the move computer makes is usually next empty cell(not always).
I am in such a desperation :)) please help me.

```
  function evaluation(arr){
    let c = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
        for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(arr[i][j] === ''){
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(arr[i][0] !== '' && arr[i][0] === arr[i][1] && arr[i][1] === arr[i][2]){
            if(arr[i][0] === player) return -10 - c;
            return 10 + c;
        } else if(arr[0][i] !== '' && arr[0][i] === arr[1][i] && arr[1][i] === arr[2][i]){
            if(arr[0][i] === player) return -10 - c;
            return 10 + c;
        } 
    }

    if(arr[1][1] !== ''){
        if(arr[0][0] === arr[1][1] && arr[1][1] === arr[2][2]){
            if(arr[1][1] === player) return -10 - c;
            return 10 + c;
        } else if(arr[0][2] === arr[1][1] && arr[1][1] === arr[2][0]){
            if(arr[1][1] === player) return -10 - c;
            return 10 + c;
        }
    }

    return 0;
  }

  function minimax(newBoard, moves, alfa, beta, maximizingPlayer){
    let e = evaluation(newBoard);
    if(moves === 0 || e !== 0){
        return e;
    }
    
    let resEval = (maximizingPlayer)? -100: 100;
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(newBoard[i][j] === ''){
                newBoard[i][j] = (maximizingPlayer)? computer: player; 
                let point = (maximizingPlayer)? minimax(newBoard, moves - 1, alfa, beta, false): minimax(newBoard, moves - 1, alfa, beta, true);
                resEval = (maximizingPlayer)? Math.max(resEval, point): Math.min(resEval, point);
                newBoard[i][j] = '';
                (maximizingPlayer)? alfa = Math.max(alfa, point): beta = Math.min(beta, point);
                if(beta <= alfa){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resEval;
  }

  function bestMove(newBoard) {
    let best = -100;
    let c1, c2;
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if (newBoard[i][j] === '') {
          newBoard[i][j] = computer;
          let mm = minimax(newBoard, moves - 1, -100, 100, false);
          if (mm > best) {
            best = mm;
            c1 = i;
            c2 = j;
          }
          newBoard[i][j] = '';
        }
      }
    }

    return { c1, c2 };
  }
```

Those are the main functions and one of them clearly doesnt work properly.
I tried making different copies of the board for every function. i tried writing different evaluation() code but that was not the problem since evaluation returns right values but somewhere in the code resEval is asiged -12 and it is a final result for every position... I also tried correcting every syntax error.

Comment: The code you have presented works fine for me (if I define the missing variable definitions to what they are supposed to be). Please provide the code with which you reproduce a problem.

Comment: @trincot https://drive.google.com/file/d/11uEIR0fvXMXX1CX6eTwWRWlGVBqXujoC/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Your question should include the way to reproduce the error. A link will not be sufficient.

Comment: error is that minimax function returns wrong values(sometimes) and mm in bestMove() is asigned wrong values. i dont know how else should i put it cuz i dont know what exactly is the problem.